# The color of the window title does not change with the flet python theme

Tags: python, flet

I would like to change the window title, how can I do this?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6r8I.png)

```py
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.theme_mode = ft.ThemeMode.DARK
    page.window_height, page.window_width = 300, 300
    page.title = 'app'
    
    page.add(ft.Text('Hello'))
ft.app(main)
```

Tried to change the theme, didn't help, and it's not in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to hide the original window title and create your own one.

Comment: Dear bugmaker, welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help if you also write about how to implement your said changes, perhaps some example code which shows your solution, would work.

Answer (score 1):

I examined your code and realized that something is missing.
You need to use an `AppBar()`.
Pros: You can change the color!
Cons: There's some limited colors...

```
page.appbar = ft.AppBar(
        title=ft.Text("AppBar Example"),
        center_title=False,
        bgcolor=ft.colors.PRIMARY)
```

You have to enter the color in `bgcolor=ft.colors.here`
Add this to the main function so you can use these limited colors:
[image: colors]

I researched a bit and found out that you can also change the `page.theme` (not the `page.theme_mode`).
I'll affect your widget's theme but it's better and nicer.

```
page.theme = Theme(color_scheme_seed="blue")
page.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line of code: `page.theme_mode = ft.ThemeMode.LIGHT`, and switched the theme from DARK to LIGHT.

Given that the default OS scheme is DARK, the Flet app originally adopted the DARK mode by default.